# How to prove G is a perfect matching

Tags: graph-theory

When I was doing my graph theory assignment, I came across such a question:
And here is my question,
Let $G$ be a bipartite graph with bipartition $(A,B)$ where $\lvert A \rvert = \lvert B \rvert = 2n$.
Suppose that $\lvert N(X) \rvert \leq \lvert X\rvert$ for every $X \subseteq A$ with $\lvert X \rvert \leq n$, and $\lvert N(Y) \rvert \leq \lvert Y \rvert$ for every $Y \subseteq B$ with $\lvert Y \rvert \leq n$. Prove that $G$ has a perfect matching.

I know that to prove a graph has a perfect matching, we have to show that for each subset $S$ on either side, we must have $\lvert N(S) \rvert \geq \lvert S \rvert$, but I just don't know how to expand the conditions given in the question to every subsets required in the proof.
I would appreciate it if you could offer some help!

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, and now I adjusted it.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).